# How to compile a library that needs the java-1.?.0-openjdk-devel library on cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, package, java

Windows: XP 32-bit

Compiler/Environment/Terminal: Cygwin(Can't use any other one)

Ram: 512 MB(Downloading Visual Studio is impossible)

Problem: I need to compile [this library](https://github.com/cs50/spl), but it needs the "java-1.?.0-openjdk-devel" package, I have did some searching around and found no way to get this package on Cygwin without Visual Studio.

Is there's a way to install the "java-1.?.0-openjdk-devel" package on cygwin? If not, is there's a package that is similiar to it that can assist in compiling this library?

Answer (score 0):

Found an [HTML file](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhg.openjdk.java.net%2Fbuild-infra%2Fjdk8%2Fraw-file%2Ftip%2FREADME-builds.html&ei=1EQdVYmhH_GP7AaV1oGoBA&usg=AFQjCNE8v5nNREzpCKSgh-J83xilTHyuJg&bvm=bv.89744112,d.ZGU&cad=rja) talking on how to build `java-1.?.0-openjdk-devel` on Cygwin.

It should help. It explain what are the binaries you should need to build it.

Comment: I can't download visual studio, my computer is 512 MB of ram